# Software resources - userland layer - lxc

Tags: linux, docker

Below is the isolation created by Linux container, for every dev setup, in a Linux machine,

[image]

---

**Question:**

Software resources involved at *Language runtime* layer are python interpreter 2.x/3.x

In development environment(having python code),

what are the software resources that are suppose to be considered at *Userland* layer?

Answer (score 3):

Diagrams like these, without context or definition of terms, are always left open to a multitude of interpretations, and you can't always just switch one label out for another.

Usually, everything that is *not kernel level* is *user level*.  Therefore, *Userland* in the diagram really encompasses all of the top levels. For example, the Python interpreter is a user level process, as is `gcc`, `ls` and the shell.

Here's another different diagram in which everything above the black line is "user level". A Linux container engine would be a user level application too.

[image: Unix Layers]

You may see your code, running inside the Python interpreter, as the "application" and any Python libraries as "library".

In the image above, the only difference between "library" and "application" is that the "library" is a set of resources or utilities that is meant to be used by other applications or libraries, whereas an "application" is meant to be used directly by a user, or it may be a service process such as `sshd`.

It's a diffuse distinction that means that if you type `cp` on the command line, you use `cp` as an application, but if you write a script that copies files using `cp`, you use `cp` as a utility in a "library" (the standard Unix shell utility toolbox).

In your diagram (where one of the boxes originally said "OS / Kernel"), since we don't know what's meant by "OS", a daemon such as `sshd` may be counted as part of "the OS" and therefore not in "userland". That's ok as long as the perspective is that of an interactive user (which does not interact *directly* with `sshd` or similar daemons). In my view, "the OS" is a bit hard to define, and may probably cover the *Kernel* and *System Interfaces* as well as possibly bits of both *Library* and *Application* in my diagram, depending on where you draw your boundaries around it.

Comment: Sorry, which binaries are coming within *userland* layer?

Comment: @overexchange Absolutely every binary that is not the kernel or a kernel module.

Comment: Binaries like `python3.6` go in *Language runtime* layer. So, can you please be specific?

Comment: @overexchange I am very specific when I say that everything that is not the kernel is userland. This is what your question was about. For a definition of "language runtime" (which also runs in userland), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900549/what-is-runtime

Comment: For your point: "without context", I would like to know, if Docker container based with userland & runtime from ubuntu or alpine or busybox or centos run on RHELinux kernel?

Comment: To be specific, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132462/3317808) is the context.

Comment: @overexchange A Docker container running Ubuntu can run on macOS, so I'm assuming it can run on RHEL as well.

Comment: So, as we know the context, can you edit saying `sshd` in userland? I am seeking some example programs from userland layer. Language runtime are like gcc, python interpretator, [jdk](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)(with jre) etc..

Comment: @overexchange As soon as you say _program_, it's in userland. There are no "programs" in kernel space.  As for the difference between "kernel" and "OS", it's still unclear in your diagram.  A system process such as `sshd` is an OS service daemon, but it's _definitely_ a userspace process.

Comment: `/bin/*`, `/lib/*`, `/usr/lib/*`. Are these part of userland layer?

Comment: @overexchange Yes to all of those.  The only thing that may be running in kernel space from any of those directories may be loadable kernel modules. But I don't know where they are usually kept (I don't use Linux).

Comment: Edited the query with new diagram